# Add new data into PHP JSON string

Tags: php, json, addition, new-operator

I have $data as JSON encoded data and I have this string:

```
$new_data = "color:'red'";
```

that needs to be added to $data so that I can read it from it as a json string.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to `json_decode($data)` first, then add the new key/value, and `json_encode()` it.

Answer (score 41):

I was just searching for the solution to this and stumbled across this question (already one year old).  The answers provided so far were not very helpful to me.  So, hopefully this helps the next person.

The answer I was looking for was

```
$json = json_decode($data,true);
```

which returns the result in an array structure, not an object.  Then, it is quite simple to add new values:

```
$json['foo'] = 'bar';
```

After this, the data can of course be returned into a string with `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$dataToAugment = json_decode($data);

// add you data here at the proper position

$data = json_encode($dataToAugment);
```