# How to add attribute in JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have Json in PHP like this:

```
$json = '{"total":"100", "page":"1", "records":"100", "rows": [ 
{"no":"1","part_number":"2","part_name":"3","price":"4","note":"8"}]}';
```

and I want to add

```
"test1":"5","test2":"7"
```

into JSON above.

so it will be like this:

```
$json = '{"total":"100", "page":"1", "records":"100", "rows": [ 
    {"no":"1","part_number":"2","part_name":"3","price":"4","test1":"5","test2":"7","note":"8"}]}';
```

Please, help me. How to add attribute in JSON in PHP?

Comment: You could parse the json string into an array using `json_decode`, add the new attributes to the array, and recreate the json string using `json_encode`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add new data into PHP JSON string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745052/add-new-data-into-php-json-string)

Comment: the examples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745052/add-new-data-into-php-json-string use array definitions.  Rio is wanting to add attributes(properties)

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364: You can simply pass `true` as second argument to `json_decode`. No difference. Apparently 4 years ago people didn't require so much hand-holding.

Comment: Beginners have always required hand-holding ;)  4 years ago there weren't as many around here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$json = '{"total":"100", "page":"1", "records":"100", "rows": [ 
{"no":"1","part_number":"2","part_name":"3","price":"4","note":"8"}]}';

// decode json
$json = json_decode($json);

// add data
$json->rows[0]->test1 = "5";
$json->rows[0]->test2 = "7";

// echo it for testing puproses
print_r($json);
// re-encode 
$json = json_encode($json);

echo $json;
```

Comment: {"total":"100","page":"1","records":"100","rows":[{"no":"1","part_number":"2","part_name":"3","price":"4","test1":"5","test2":"7","note":"8"}],"test1":"5","test2":"7"}                       its your final output.does not match to what is wanted

Comment: it should be like this:

{"total":"100","page":"1","records":"100","rows":[{"no":"1","part_number":"2","p‌​art_name":"3","price":"4","test1":"5","test2":"7","note":"8"}]}

not like this:
{"total":"100","page":"1","records":"100","rows":[{"no":"1","part_number":"2","p‌​art_name":"3","price":"4","note":"8"}],"test1":"5","test2‌​":"7"}

Comment: yeah sharif that's the output but not match to what is wanted, can you help me?

Comment: yeah @RioEduardo .i also mentioned this.

Comment: @user20232359723568423 - nah, that's the answer, thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 i have alos tried like this.here is your ans.

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 - one more, how about in javascript? can you give me an example? :)

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216632/how-to-add-attribute-in-json-in-javascript