# How to add attribute in JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON in Javascript like this:

```
var json = {
    "total": "100",
    "page":"1",
    "records":"100",
    "rows": [
        {
            "no": "1",
            "part_number": "2",
            "part_name": "3",
            "price": "4",
            "note": "8"
        }
    ]
};
```

and I want to add

```
"test1":"5",
"test2":"7"
```

into JSON above.

so it will be like this:

```
var json = {
    "total":"100",
    "page":"1",
    "records":"100",
    "rows": [
        {
            "no": "1",
            "part_number": "2",
            "part_name": "3",
            "price": "4",
            "test1": "5",
            "test2": "7",
            "note":"8"
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: You have an object literal, not JSON. [Learn more about objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). Also have a look at this question: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).

Answer (score 2):

```
json["rows"][0]["test1"] = "5";
json["rows"][0]["test2"] = "7";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
json.rows[0].test1=5; // or if you want "5"
json.rows[0].test2=7;
```