# Merge two json array into one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen, lumen-5.4

Tried merging two JSON responses into a single one but the problem is the data is displayed in two arrays and I want it in a single array. How do I achieve it in Lumen/Laravel

Tried contatinating two arrays or responses

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $post = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        $post_images = PostImage::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return $this->successResponse($posts.$post_image );        
    }
```

Expected:-

```
{
    "post": {
        "id": 14,
        "post_id": 798965728,
        "user_id": 1,
        "location": "first",
        "title": "un8852",
        "cooked_time": "1554329910",
        "dispose_time": "1554373110",
        "food_type": "nv",
        "description": "asdfg",
        "serve_quantity": 23,
        "lat": 19.08,
        "lon": 73,    
        "id": 10,
        "post_id": 798965728,
        "image_name1": null,
        "image_name2": null,
        "image_name3": null,
        "image_name4": null,
        "image_name5": null,
    },
    "st": "1",
    "msg": "success"
}
```

Got:-

```
{
   "post":"{\"id\":14,\"post_id\":798965728,\"user_id\":1,\"location\":\"first\",\"title\":\"un8852\",\"cooked_time\":\"1554329910\",\"dispose_time\":\"1554373110\",\"food_type\":\"nv\",\"description\":\"asdfg\",\"serve_quantity\":23,\"lat\":19.08,\"lon\":73,\"created_at\":\"2019-04-04 10:20:18\",\"updated_at\":\"2019-04-04 10:20:18\"}{\"id\":10,\"post_id\":798965728,\"image_name1\":null,\"image_name2\":null,\"image_name3\":null,\"image_name4\":null,\"image_name5\":null,\"created_at\":\"2019-04-04 10:20:18\",\"updated_at\":\"2019-04-04 10:20:18\"}",
   "st":"1",
   "msg":"success"
}
```

Comment: May help if you include the source data, we have expected results, actual results, but not that [source data] - which is well ... kind of important.

Comment: I can tell you, You'll prolly want to use `array_replace_recursive($primary, $secondary)` after `json_decoding` them both.  **PS** prolly  is not a word, but I like it.  Ok .. turns out it is [oxforddictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prolly)   :-(

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix can you help me with this kind of problem            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593703/how-to-update-requests-where-multiple-db-are-use-and-images-are-involve

Comment: Unfortunately I have yet to use Laravel, I'm actually in the planing stage of getting a project done for my work using it, but we are going it initial outsource it as I am too busy with other things.  But I plan to build on it later, basically it's a CRUD system for our incoming data, which should be fairly easy to do.  Then later I plant to build onto it.  Currently we use mainly Code Igniter 2, which I built about 5 years ago and continue to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some missing pieces there, but I think I see what's happening.

Based on the result you're getting, it looks like `$posts` and `$post_image` in this code are eloquent models.

```
return $this->successResponse($posts.$post_image );
```

When you concatenate them, their `__toString()` methods convert them to strings, which is done using the `toJson()` method. So basically you have two JSON objects stuck together, which isn't valid JSON, and then the `successResponse()` method encodes them again.

To merge them, you can convert them to arrays, merge those, then pass the result to `successResponse()`.

```
$merged = array_merge($posts->toArray(), $post_image->toArray());
return $this->successResponse($merged);
```

The result you want is impossible, though. The "post" object has two different values of "id". You'll only be able to get one. If you use

```
$merged = array_merge($posts->toArray(), $post_image->toArray());
```

Then the id value of the second object will replace the first one. If you want to keep the first id value, you need to use union instead of `array_merge`.

```
$merged = $a->toArray() + $b->toArray();
```

Comment: Help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593703/how-to-update-requests-where-multiple-db-are-use-and-images-are-involve

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't concatenate 2 JSON objects as strings.

The proper way would be to:

1. Get the Post and the PostImage objects

   $post = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

   $post_images = PostImage::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
2. Serialize the Post object
   https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization
3. Use the method described below to  add each field of the PostImage object (image_name1 .. image_name5) to the JSON 
   [How to add attribute in JSON in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196256/how-to-add-attribute-in-json-in-php)
4. Return the JSON

Update:

Post::orderBy('id','DESC')->get()-> first() returns one object.

Post::orderBy('id','DESC')->get() returns a collection of objects and it would require a different approach.

Try this:

```
$post = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

$post->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $post_images = PostImage::where('post_id', $item->id)->get()->first();
    $item->setAttribute('image_name1',$post_images->image_name1);
    $item->setAttribute('image_name2',$post_images->image_name2);
    $item->setAttribute('image_name3',$post_images->image_name3);
    $item->setAttribute('image_name4',$post_images->image_name4);
    $item->setAttribute('image_name5',$post_images->image_name5);
    return $item;
});

return $this->successResponse($posts);
```

Comment: but it works fine if I try for $post = Post::orderBy('id','DESC')->get()-> first() values but not for all when i remove first() function. It specifies that image_name1 doesnt exist in collection

Comment: I updated the answer. If that doesn't work for you please explain in more details what you want to do.

Comment: can you check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593703/how-to-update-requests-where-multiple-db-are-use-and-images-are-involve

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely concatenate two JSON arrays, You have to parse the objects and  concatenate them and re stringify.

This question might be answered here also. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10384890/1684254

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593703/how-to-update-requests-where-multiple-db-are-use-and-images-are-involve