# Include URI to resource in API response

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

I'm working on improving an already existing API(Instagram) to level 3 in the [Richardsons Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

Basically, I want to include a uri to the resource in the API response.

Here is an example. This is a JSON representation of of a user resource.

```
{
    "username": "emil",
    "bio": "",
    "website": "",
    "profile_picture": "https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg",
    "full_name": "Yes",
    "id": "1279132381" 
}
```

As you can see, we get the id of this user. I then want to be able to include a uri to that resource in the JSON, like this.

```
{
    "username": "emil",
    "bio": "",
    "website": "",
    "profile_picture": "https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg",
    "full_name": "Yes",
    "id": "1279132381",
    "uri": "users/1279132381"
}
```

Here we have a URI to the user resource included in the response, this is want I want to be able to do.

I do not know where to start really. I can successfully utilize the Instagram API and get the original data but I don't know what to do next.

Suggestions on how I can accomplish this is greatly appreciated. I think there might be som kind of library to simplify this but I have not found anything yet.

I am developing in PHP using the Laravel framework.

Thank you!

Comment: you may take a look at this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745052/add-new-data-into-php-json-string)

Answer (score 0):

Example in your case :

```
$arr = array(
    'username' => "emil",
    'bio' => "",
    'website' => "",
    'profile_picture' => "https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg",
    'full_name' => "Yes",
    'id' => "1279132381"
    );

$arr['uri'] = 'users/1279132381';

echo json_encode($arr);
```