# How to insert a new key value to the existing JSON- PHP

Tags: php

I have been searching online for the past 2 hours and couldn't find an answer. I have some data stored in my database in JSON format. I want to add a new key and value to the json data. Example

```
{
    "systemService":"1234",
    "DATA_PLAN":"SMEF",
    "amount":"5000"
}


$message = .$name "" .$post;
```

I want to add a new key and value to it. `"message":$message`

to something like this.

```
{
    "systemService":"1234",
    "DATA_PLAN":"SMEF",
    "amount":"5000"
    "message":"mike accountance"
}
```

How do I go about it in PHP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new data into PHP JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745052/add-new-data-into-php-json-string)

Comment: No @El_Vanja it doesn't

Comment: And how exactly does it not? What have you tried to determine that it doesn't suit your problem? That question explains exactly what you're asking about, so unless you can prove on a concrete example that it does not, I believe the problem is that you don't understand something in the process. If you need clarification, edit your question with your attempt and explain where and how it fails to perform the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do it:

**Method 1 decoding it to an associative array:**

```
$object = json_decode('{
        "systemService":"1234",
        "DATA_PLAN":"SMEF",
        "amount":"5000"
    }', true);
    
$object['message'] = "Your message";
    
echo json_encode($object); //this will give you the json string with your new property
```

**Method 2 decoding it to an object:**

```
$object = json_decode('{
        "systemService":"1234",
        "DATA_PLAN":"SMEF",
        "amount":"5000"
    }');
    
$object->message = "Your message";
    
echo json_encode($object); //this will give you the json string with your new property
```

Comment: I am receiving this error, '''attempting to assign property 'message' of non-object. I wanted to use a data in the json to generate a new key and value. I am getting the about error, could it be because I called $planer = $object["$plan"];?

Comment: You can try to decode your json to an associative array with `json_decode("your json-string", true);` and then assign the value with `$object['message'] = "your message";`

Comment: But I think thats not the reason for your problem. Please provide your new code.

Comment: Thanks it now works, changing to array is very ok

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the JSON string to object (with PHP [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function), add the new property, then convert it back to string (with PHP [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function), *i.e.*:

```
$str = '{
  "systemService": "1234",
  "DATA_PLAN": "SMEF",
  "amount": "5000"
}';
$obj = json_decode($str);
$obj->message = 'mike accountance';
$str = json_encode($obj);
echo $str;
```

Comment: I am receving this error, '''attempting to assign property 'message' of non-object