# Adding dynamic data to a json literal string

Tags: php, json

I have this json literal string

```
{  
    "properties_form_data": {  
        "user_id":"edhdh83883737364623",
        "property_owner":"rammstein",   
        "property_name": "rockers",   
        "property_address":"hard metal",
        "property_coordinates": true,  
        "property_type": true,  
        "property_country": true,  
        "property_district": true,  
        "property_region": "description",
        "property_city": "description",
        "property_profile": "description",
        "checkin_time": "description",
        "checkin_out_time": "description which is "afraid"",
        "pets_allowed": false,
        "age_restriction_for_checkin": true,
        "property_images":{"property_s3_image_links":"1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg","date_updated":"95356373773"},
        "property_amenities":{"together":true,"prospering":true,"touring_right_now":false},
        "sorrounding_areas":[{
            "album_id": "23883838dhhskk89968654s",
            "album_name":"Rammstein",
            "date_taken":"35356373773"
        }],
        "restaurants":[{
            "album_id": "23883838dhhskk89968654s",
            "album_name":"Rammstein",
            "date_taken":"35356373773"
        }],
        "date_inserted":"hard metal", 
        "updated_on": true      
    }  
}
```

I am getting some data from the client that i want to add to the string then encode it and store it away.I am receiving several data sets as arrays and i wanted to add that as well by looping and encoding the resulting json literal string

```
  <?php
    $no = '';
$h = rand(6,99999);
$newarr = array(6,9,8,0,7);
print_r($newarr);

for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
         $no = '{
                    "album_id": "'.$x.'",
                    "album_name":"Rammstein",
                    "date_taken":"35356373773"
                }';
        }
$jl ='{  
    "properties_form_data": {  
        "user_id":"edhdh83883737364623",
        "property_owner":"rammstein",   
        "property_name": "'.$h.'",   
        "property_address":"hard metal",
        "property_coordinates": true,  
        "property_type": true,  
        "property_country": true,  
        "property_district": true,  
        "property_region": "description",
        "property_city": "description",
        "property_profile": "description",
        "checkin_time": "description",
        "checkin_out_time": "description which is "afraid"",
        "pets_allowed": false,
        "age_restriction_for_checkin": true,
        "property_images":{"property_s3_image_links":"1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg","date_updated":"95356373773"},
        "property_amenities":{"together":true,"prospering":true,"touring_right_now":false},
        "sorrounding_areas":['.$no.'],
        "restaurants":[{
            "album_id": "23883838dhhskk89968654s",
            "album_name":"Rammstein",
            "date_taken":"35356373773"
        }],
        "date_inserted":"hard metal", 
        "updated_on": true      
    }  
}';
echo '<pre>';
echo $jl;
echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

php complains that i can't use the for loop from inside the json literal which is a problem because i have several arrays i want to add. How can i add the array data in the json literal string?.

Comment: Don't build JSON manually. Decode it, add new elements, re-encode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new data into PHP JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745052/add-new-data-into-php-json-string)

Comment: Aside from that, you're trying to use `echo` inside an assignment (illegal) and you're trying to use `+` to concatenate (mixing up JS and PHP syntax).

Comment: ? no it doesn't. Specifically, i wanted to add in array data for a very specific use case.

Comment: The + is an error i want to concatenta ewith dot, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Doesn't answer in what way? It describes the principle I mentioned in the first comment. Manually editing a JSON string is just asking for trouble. Let PHP do the work.

Comment: I would not go that far, with all due respect, i have a use case and i would appreciate if i had an informed opinion to not ask, but here we are, thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything specific about your use case. Unless you can provide more information as to why your use case is specific and the described method of solving this issue is not applicable to it, I stand by my duplicate flag.

Answer (score 0):

Did form the json literal using an anonymous function and made sure it produces valid json by adding or omitting last element comma,based on the length of the array

```
 <?php
    $newarr = array(6,9,8,0,7);
    
      
    $of = function()
    {
    $h = rand(6,99999);
    $comma_resolution = '';
    $jl ='{  
        "properties_form_data": {  
            "user_id":"edhdh83883737364623",
            "property_owner":"rammstein",   
            "property_name": "'.$h.'",   
            "property_address":"hard metal",
            "property_coordinates": true,  
            "property_type": true,  
            "property_country": true,  
            "property_district": true,  
            "property_region": "description",
            "property_city": "description",
            "property_profile": "description",
            "checkin_time": "description",
            "checkin_out_time": "description which is afraid",
            "pets_allowed": false,
            "age_restriction_for_checkin": true,
            "property_images":{"property_s3_image_links":"1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg","date_updated":"95356373773"},
            "property_amenities":{"together":true,"prospering":true,"touring_right_now":false},
            "sorrounding_areas":[';
            echo $jl;
            $possible_array_length = 4;
            for ($x = 0; $x <= $possible_array_length; $x++) {
            if($x === $possible_array_length){
            $comma_resolution = '';
            }
            else{
            $comma_resolution = ',';
            }
             echo '{
                        "album_id": "'.$x.'",
                        "album_name":"Rammstein",
                        "date_taken":"35356373773"
            }'.$comma_resolution.'';
            }
            
            $second = '],
            "restaurants":[{
                "album_id": "23883838dhhskk89968654s",
                "album_name":"Rammstein",
                "date_taken":"35356373773"
            }],
            "date_inserted":"hard metal", 
            "updated_on": true      
        }  
    }';
    echo $second;
    };
    
    echo '<pre>';
    $of();
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```